# how to iterate list in django html template

Tags: html, django, list

I have a list that i put in table in template in Django:

`<tr><th></th>{% for year in years %}<th>{{ year }}</th>{% endfor %}</tr>`

```
years=[2020,2019,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014,2013....2002,2001,2000]
```

i want only print the last 5 years from the list

```
years=[2020,2019,2018,2017,2016]
```

so i tried:

<`tr><th></th>{% for year in years %}<th>{{ year[:4] }}</th>{% endfor %}</tr>`

however this way it does not work. How to iterate only 5 years from the list instead of 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for year in years|slice:":5" %}
```